# How to get frame delay from animated gif?

Tags: delphi, gif

I try resize animated gif.
I resize each frame as bitmap and then make new animated gif 
but I don't know how to get frame delay for same speed animation as in original gif.

```
uses Gifimg;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  gif: TGIFImage;
  bmp,bmp2: TBitmap;
  i:integer;
  gifren: TGIFRenderer;
  gif2:TGifImage;
begin
  gif:=TGIFImage.Create;
  gif2:=tgifimage.Create;
  bmp:=TBitmap.Create;
  bmp2:=TBitmap.Create;
    gif.LoadFromFile('d:\z.gif');
    gifren:=TGIFRenderer.Create(gif);
      for i:=0 to gif.Images.Count-1 do begin
      bmp.SetSize(gif.Width, gif.Height);
      gifren.Draw(bmp.Canvas, bmp.Canvas.ClipRect);
       bmp2.SetSize(1111,1111);
        bmp2.Canvas.StretchDraw(Rect(0, 0, 1111, 1111), bmp);

        TGIFGraphicControlExtension.Create(gif2.add(bmp2)).Delay:=10;
        gifren.NextFrame;
      end;
   TGIFAppExtNSLoop.Create(Gif2.Images.Frames[0]).Loops:=0;
   Gif2.SaveToFile('d:\gif.gif');
 end;
```

Comment: you may want to upvote the accepted answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to help [Vcl.Imaging.GIFImg.TGIFRenderer.FrameDelay](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Imaging.GIFImg.TGIFRenderer.FrameDelay)

> Specifies the delay time before moving to the next frame in an
>   animated GIF.

But do consider that the resized image may require more time to render, and it may not be possible to keep up the pace.

Comment: GIF delay time is measured in 1/100ths of a second, @Wataru. I'm not sure why you assumed that the value was in milliseconds.

Comment: with divide 10 I get same animation speed as in original gif

Comment: @Waturo You really aren't listening. Nor are you providing any information. You say you divide something by 10 but you don't say what that something is. My intuition tells me that something is a value measured in milliseconds.

Comment: TGIFGraphicControlExtension.Create(gif2.add(bmp2)).Delay:=GIFRen.FrameDelay div 10;

Comment: So now you've introduced TGIFGraphicControlExtension.Delay.