# Extract a frame from a gif using GifImage

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, gif, delphi-2010, delphi-6

How to extract frames from a gif using GifImage 2.X which does not have TGifRenderer?

This is how I try but the frames are incomplete (half empty):

```
  Gif := TGifImage.Create;
  Gif.LoadFromFile('test.gif');

  Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  Bmp.PixelFormat := pf24bit;
  Bmp.Width := Gif.Width;
  Bmp.Height := Gif.Height;

  for i:=0 to Gif.Images.Count-1 do begin

    Bmp.Assign(Gif.Images.SubImages[i].Bitmap);

    Bmp.SaveToFile('out/' + IntToStr(i) + '.bmp');

  end;
```

Comment: Delphi's native [`TGIFImage`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Imaging.GIFImg.TGIFImage) does not have an `Images.SubImages[]` property, it should be `Images.Frames[]` instead, eg: `Gif.Images.Frames[i].Bitmap`

Comment: @Remy Version 3.X is native to new Delphis. For older Delphis there is 2.X here http://www.tolderlund.eu/delphi/

Comment: You are positive that what you call half empty is not the differential image from the previous frame?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Most likely it is a differential image but how to get a full image?

Comment: By rendering... How could it be possible to construct the full image without having all information?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Sure thing. But I can't find any function to render the image

Comment: The "related" section have a dupe, which also links to a followup.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz This one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35521931/ It requires version 3.X

Comment: I was rather thinking [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136993/how-to-extract-frames-from-a-tgifimage-into-bitmaps?rq=1). Why can't you use version 3?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Version 3.X is only bundled with new Delphis because the author sold it to Embarcadero. Version 2.X is freely available to everyone.

Comment: You might want to add your specific Delphi version tag to the question.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz The version 2.X works with Delphi 2 to Delphi 2010. Should I add all these versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution for version 2.X available for download from http://www.tolderlund.eu/delphi/
Gir frames can have various disposal methods set. The approach below doesn't support this but it works fine for most GIFS.

```
  Gif := TGifImage.Create;
  Gif.LoadFromFile('test.gif');

  Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  Bmp.PixelFormat := pf24bit;
  Bmp.Width := Gif.Width;
  Bmp.Height := Gif.Height;

  for i:=0 to Gif.Images.Count-1 do begin
    if GIF.Images[i].Empty then Continue; //skip empty          

    Gif.Images[i].Bitmap.TransparentColor := Gif.Images[i].GraphicControlExtension.TransparentColor;

    if i <> 0 then Gif.Images[i].Bitmap.Transparent := True;

    //you should also take care of various disposal methods:
    //Gif.Images[i].GraphicControlExtension.Disposal    

    Bmp.Canvas.Draw(0,0, Gif.Images[i].Bitmap);

    Bmp.SaveToFile('out/' + IntToStr(i) + '.bmp');

  end;
```

A different solution is to use TGIFPainter but then it won't work in a loop.

```
Bmp: TBitmap; //global

...

Gif := TGifImage.Create;
Gif.LoadFromFile('test.gif');
Gif.DrawOptions := GIF.DrawOptions - [goLoop, goLoopContinously, goAsync];
Gif.OnAfterPaint := AfterPaintGIF;
Gif.Paint(Bmp.Canvas, Bmp.Canvas.ClipRect, GIF.DrawOptions);

...

procedure TForm1.AfterPaintGIF(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not (Sender is TGIFPainter) then Exit;
  if not Assigned(Bmp) then Exit;    
  Bmp.Canvas.Lock;
  try
    Bmp.SaveToFile('out/' + IntToStr(TGIFPainter(Sender).ActiveImage) + '.bmp');
  finally
    Bmp.Canvas.Unlock;
  end;
end;
```

And the solution for version 3.X is super easy:

```
  Gif := TGifImage.Create;
  Gif.LoadFromFile('test.gif');

  Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  Bmp.PixelFormat := pf24bit;
  Bmp.Width := Gif.Width;
  Bmp.Height := Gif.Height;

  GR := TGIFRenderer.Create(GIF);
  GR.Animate := True;

  for i:=0 to Gif.Images.Count-1 do begin

    if GIF.Images[i].Empty then Continue; //skip empty

    GR.Draw(Bmp.Canvas, Bmp.Canvas.ClipRect);
    GR.NextFrame;

    Bmp.SaveToFile('out/' + IntToStr(i) + '.bmp');
 end;
```